# Why turning these macro-functions to functions didn't work correctly?

Tags: c, macros, microcontroller

I'm using some macros that initializes & writes & reads port or port pin: 
(And it works fine)

```
/* GPIO port operations */
#define GPIO_InitPort(CONTROL, DIRECTION)   ((CONTROL) = ((DIRECTION)? (~GPIO_OUT):(GPIO_OUT)))
#define GPIO_WritePort(PORT, DATA)          ((PORT) = (DATA))
#define GPIO_ReadPort(PORT)                 (PORT)

/* GPIO port pin operations */
#define GPIO_InitPortPin(CONTROL, PIN, DIRECTION)   ((CONTROL) = (CONTROL & (~(1 << PIN)))|(DIRECTION << PIN))
#define GPIO_WritePortPin(PORT, PIN, DATA)          ((PORT) = (PORT & (~(1 << PIN)))|(DATA << PIN))
#define GPIO_ReadPortPin(PORT, PIN)                 (((PORT) & (1 << PIN)) >> (PIN))
```

And, i was thinking to make a GPIO module, its functions implemented as follows:

```
void GPIO_InitPort(uint8 PortControl, uint8 PortDir){
    PortControl = ((PortDir) ?  (~GPIO_OUT) : (GPIO_OUT));
}

void GPIO_WritePort(uint8 PortData, uint8 PortLevel){
    PortData = PortLevel;
}

uint8 GPIO_ReadPort(uint8 PortData){
    return PortData;
}
void GPIO_InitPortPin(uint8 PortControl, uint8 Pin, uint8 PinDir){
    PortControl &= ( ~(1<<Pin) | (PinDir<<Pin) );
}
uint8 GPIO_ReadPortPin(uint8 PortData, uint8 PinLevel){
    return (( PortData & (1<<PinLevel) ) >> PinLevel);
}
void GPIO_WritePortPin(uint8 PortData, uint8 Pin, uint8 PinLevel){
    PortData &= ( ~(1<<Pin) | (PinLevel<<Pin) );
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work, although same logic used.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Doesn't compile? Doesn't run? Doesn't toggle some LED lights?

Comment: Your functions do not have semantics identical to the macros', though they are similar.  If you want us to tell you about why the differences affect your results then you'll need to present a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Functions receive parameters by copy, so all the changes that your functions make to their parameters are not reflected to the variables/registers that get passed by the callers.

Comment: Compiles, but didn't work as expected @usr2564301

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that macros are just text substitutions - macro arguments are not *evaluated*, they are simply expanded in place.  If you write something like

```
GPIO_InitPort( foo, bar );
```

the preprocessor expands that to

```
((foo) = ((bar) ? (~GPIO_OUT) : (GPIO_OUT)));
```

Function arguments, OTOH, *are* evaluated, and the result of that evaluation is passed to the function.  Remember that C uses pass-by-value semantics - the formal argument is a different object in memory than the actual argument, so updating one has no effect on the other.  If you call the *function*

```
GPIO_InitPort( foo, bar );
```

the *formal* argument `PortControl` is a different object in memory from the *actual* argument `foo`, and similarly `PortDir` is a separate object from `bar`.  Writing to `PortControl` has absolutely no effect on `foo`.

If you want a function to write to the actual parameter in the caller, then you must pass a pointer to that parameter.  So `GPIO_InitPort` would need to be written as

```
void GPIO_InitPort( uint8 *PortControl, uint8 PortDir )
{
  *PortControl = PortDir ? ~GPIO_OUT : GPIO_OUT;
}
```

and called as

```
GPIO_InitPort( &foo, bar );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about pointers.

Example:

```
void changeVar(int *var, int source)
{
    *var = source;
}

int main()
{
    int foobar;

    changeVar(&foobar, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might like to *also* explain how your proposed solution relates to the question.